# How do I get a unix timestamp from PHP date time?

Tags: php, unix-timestamp

I'm trying to get a unix timestamp with PHP but it doesn't seem to be working.  Here is the format I'm trying to convert to a unix timestamp:

PHP

```
$datetime = '2012-07-25 14:35:08';

$unix_time = date('Ymdhis', strtotime($datetime ));
echo $unix_time;
```

My result looks like this:

```
20120725023508
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

[strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) Returns a `timestamp` on success, FALSE otherwise.

```
 echo strtotime('2012-07-25 14:35:08' );
```

Output

```
1343219708
```

Comment: ahh..trying to make it harder then it needs to be.  Thanks!

Comment: @Baba But strtotime is timezone specific, isn't it ?

Comment: CAREFUL!  `strtotime` assumes the time string is in the time zone specified by php's current `date_default_timezone_get`.  If unsure, FIRST call `date_default_timezone_set` with the timezone name that corresponds to the source of your date strings.

Answer (score 3):

This is converting it to a unix timestamp: `strtotime($datetime)`, but you're converting it back to a date again with `date()`.

Answer (score 3):

To extend the answers here with an object-oriented solution, the DateTime class must be named. The DateTime class is available since PHP 5.2 and can be used as follows.

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2012-07-25 14:35:08');
echo $date->getTimestamp(); // output: 1343219708
```

Or even as a one-liner

```
echo $date = (new DateTime('2012-07-25 14:35:08'))->getTimestamp();
// output: 1343219708
```