# sort multidimensional array by date

Tags: php

I have this `array`:-

```
array (size=8)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'date' => string '17/05/2016 00:00:00' (length=19)
      'reason' => string 'DNA' (length=3)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'date' => string '10/05/2016 00:00:00' (length=19)
      'reason' => string 'UTA' (length=3)
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      'date' => string '03/05/2016 00:00:00' (length=19)
      'reason' => string 'DNA' (length=3)
  3 => 
    array (size=2)
      'date' => string '26/04/2016 00:00:00' (length=19)
      'reason' => string 'true' (length=4)
  4 => 
    array (size=2)
      'date' => string '31/05/2016 00:00:00' (length=19)
      'reason' => string 'true' (length=4)
  5 => 
    array (size=2)
      'date' => string '24/05/2016 00:00:00' (length=19)
      'reason' => string 'true' (length=4)
  6 => 
    array (size=2)
      'date' => string '07/06/2016 00:00:00' (length=19)
      'reason' => string 'true' (length=4)
  7 => 
    array (size=2)
      'date' => string '14/06/2016 00:00:00' (length=19)
      'reason' => string 'true' (length=4)
```

I want to sort it by 'date'

I tried both of the following methods, but the result ( below )is not sorted correctly.

```
usort($course, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['date'] - $b['date'];
});

_______________________________
function date_compare($a, $b)
{
    $t1 = strtotime($a['date']);
    $t2 = strtotime($b['date']);
    return $t1 - $t2;
}
usort($course, 'date_compare');
```

This is the "sorted" array

```
array (size=8)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'date' => string '24/05/2016 00:00:00' (length=19)
      'reason' => string 'true' (length=4)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'date' => string '14/06/2016 00:00:00' (length=19)
      'reason' => string 'true' (length=4)
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      'date' => string '31/05/2016 00:00:00' (length=19)
      'reason' => string 'true' (length=4)
  3 => 
    array (size=2)
      'date' => string '26/04/2016 00:00:00' (length=19)
      'reason' => string 'true' (length=4)
  4 => 
    array (size=2)
      'date' => string '17/05/2016 00:00:00' (length=19)
      'reason' => string 'DNA' (length=3)
  5 => 
    array (size=2)
      'date' => string '03/05/2016 00:00:00' (length=19)
      'reason' => string 'DNA' (length=3)
  6 => 
    array (size=2)
      'date' => string '07/06/2016 00:00:00' (length=19)
      'reason' => string 'true' (length=4)
  7 => 
    array (size=2)
      'date' => string '10/05/2016 00:00:00' (length=19)
      'reason' => string 'UTA' (length=3)
```

Comment: Does the data come from Database? If so why not sorting via mysql first?

Comment: First `usort()` will not work as you are comparing strings, not dates. So you mean `date_compare` function is not working? Use PHPFiddle to provide example: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/

Comment: String `24/05/2016 00:00:00` can not be converted to datetime, because strtotime expects  month first. Use create from format - http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Comment: @DarraghEnright - Its not a duplicate, as that is where I got the 2nd function from

Comment: The data does not come directly from the DB, its been handled before ariving to this point so thats why I cant sort on query thanks.

Comment: Yeah - I just realised! Retracted.

Comment: Kindly try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16306416/sort-php-multi-dimensional-array-based-on-key

Comment: `array_multisort` is suitable for your case, check out this document, it explain  how to use this method clearly  http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php

Comment: @morne  can you let me know why you unmarked me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to modify the datetime strings in your `$course` array in order to make them comparable in the manner that you want.

One (flexible) way to do this is to create [`DateTime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) objects from your datetime strings and compare those.

A quick note about datetimes: standard US format `m/d/Y` uses forward slashes, and standard European format `d-m-Y` uses hyphens. Your datetime strings are a mixture of both, using US-style forward slashes with European day/month/year ordering.

Therefore you'll have to take an additional step to parse each datetime string into a valid `DateTime()` object before comparing.

Static method [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) can help in this regard. For example, given an array called `$course`:

```php
$course = [
    [
        'date' => '17/05/2016 00:00:00',
        'reason' => 'DNA',
    ],
    [
        'date'   => '10/05/2016 00:00:00',
        'reason' => 'UTA',
    ],
    [
        'date'   => '03/05/2016 00:00:00',
        'reason' => 'DNA',
    ],
    [
        'date'   => '26/04/2016 00:00:00',
        'reason' => 'true',
    ],
    [
        'date'   => '31/05/2016 00:00:00',
        'reason' => 'true',
    ],
    [
        'date'   => '24/05/2016 00:00:00',
        'reason' => 'true',
    ],
    [
        'date'   => '07/06/2016 00:00:00',
        'reason' => 'true',
    ],
    [
        'date'   => '14/06/2016 00:00:00',
        'reason' => 'true',
    ],
];
```

You can then apply a callback with `usort()` which converts the `date` value of each comparison object into a valid `DateTime()` objects before comparing them:

```php
usort($course, function ($a, $b) {
    $dateA = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s', $a['date']);
    $dateB = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s', $b['date']);
    // ascending ordering, use `<=` for descending
    return $dateA >= $dateB;
});

print_r($course);
```

This yields:

```php
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date] => 26/04/2016 00:00:00
            [reason] => true
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [date] => 03/05/2016 00:00:00
            [reason] => DNA
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [date] => 10/05/2016 00:00:00
            [reason] => UTA
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [date] => 17/05/2016 00:00:00
            [reason] => DNA
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [date] => 24/05/2016 00:00:00
            [reason] => true
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [date] => 31/05/2016 00:00:00
            [reason] => true
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [date] => 07/06/2016 00:00:00
            [reason] => true
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [date] => 14/06/2016 00:00:00
            [reason] => true
        )

)
```

If your course array is very large, then there may be some overhead in creating `DateTime` objects on the fly like the example above. YMMV. In this case, I'd consider mapping over the array first and create `DateTime` objects for each entry, and then apply `usort()`.

Note that, with a standard format datetime string, such as European `d-m/Y H:i:s`, US `m/d/Y H:i:s` or IS08601 `Y-m-d H:i:s`, you can simply pass the datetime string as the first value into the `DateTime` constructor instead; e.g:

```php
$dt = new DateTime($someStandardFormatDateTimeString);
```

Apologies about the errant close vote earlier. I've removed that now.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a new array and use the index and `unix timestamp` then it should be a simple `asort`

`$unix_time = date('Ymdhis', strtotime($datetime ));`

[PHP asort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php)

[How do I get a unix timestamp from PHP date time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12802987/how-do-i-get-a-unix-timestamp-from-php-date-time)

Comment: That does not really answer PO's question