# How to sort a 3 dimensional array by element containing date, from newest to oldest

Tags: php, sorting, date, datetime, multidimensional-array

I have a 3 dimensional array whose structure looks like the following. Let's call the inner-most arrays as records for clarity. I need to sort the outermost array in such a way that it gets sorted from newest to oldest.

```
Array (
[0] => Array (
        [0] => Array (
                         [personNum] => 2
                         [type] => comment
                         [datetime] => 2019-05-15 11:29:45
                     ),
        [1] => Array (
                         [personNum] => 3
                         [type] => status
                         [datetime] => 2019-05-26 15:59:53
                     )
       ),

[1] => Array (
        [0] => Array (
                         [personNum] => 3
                         [type] => status
                         [datetime] => 2019-05-26 15:59:53
                     )
        [1] => Array (
                         [personNum] => 4
                         [type] => status
                         [datetime] => 2019-05-26 16:04:24
                     )
      )
)
```

I have checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910611/php-sort-a-multidimensional-array-by-element-containing-date) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38093669/sort-multidimensional-array-by-date) links, and I know that custom functions is the way to go, and i am trying to understand it for 2D arrays but i am not getting a hang of how it would work for 3D arrays.

Comment: Please use `var_export()` instead of `var_dump()` when you show arrays to SO.

Comment: Do you want to sort the innermost arrays as well as the outermost array?

Comment: @Nick Yep. Sorry power outage is the reason of late reply

Comment: @MorganFreeFarm I see! Thank you sir I will

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this as a two-stage process. First, use `array_walk` with `array_multisort` to sort the inner arrays by `datetime`. Then use `usort`, comparing the maximum `datetime` values from the inner arrays:

```
array_walk($arr, function (&$v) { array_multisort(array_column($v, 'datetime'), SORT_DESC, $v); });
usort($arr, function ($a, $b) {
    return strcmp(max(array_column($b, 'datetime')), max(array_column($a, 'datetime')));
});
print_r($arr);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [personNum] => 4
                    [type] => status
                    [datetime] => 2019-05-26 16:04:24
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [personNum] => 3
                    [type] => status
                    [datetime] => 2019-05-26 15:59:53
                )
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [personNum] => 3
                    [type] => status
                    [datetime] => 2019-05-26 15:59:53
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [personNum] => 2
                    [type] => comment
                    [datetime] => 2019-05-15 11:29:45
                )
        )
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/suPr4)

Answer (score 1):

You can attempt to use usort:
  Sort an array by values using a user-defined comparison function 
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

```
usort($allArray,function($a,$b){
     return $a[0]['dateTime']-$b[0]['dateTime'];
})
```